# Check if toggle true addClass else if not removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**(Thank you guys ... I have fix it)**

Please I need your help if you can

I want when the toggle are show ... addClass "activeee" and remove it from other div's and when the toggle are hide removeClass

My problem is : when I click on the toggle to hide it (toggle hide) it's have been hide but the Class don't remove
this is my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    $("#mashmenu-mod-1").click(function(){
         $(".mod-content").fadeOut();
        var mod1 = $(this).find(".mod-content").toggle();
        mod1;
        var Checkmod1 = $(this).find(".mod-content").data("toggled", "true"); 

        if(Checkmod1) {
            $("#mashmenu-mod-1").addClass("activeee");
        } else {
            $("#mashmenu-mod-1").removeClass("activeee");
        }
    });

    $("#mashmenu-mod-2").click(function(){
        $(".mod-content").fadeOut();
        $(this).find(".mod-content").toggle();
    });


    $("#mashmenu-mod-3").click(function(){
        $(".mod-content").fadeOut();
        $(this).find(".mod-content").toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: What is not working with the code shown?

Comment: My problem is : when I click on the toggle to hide it (toggle hide) it's have been hide but the Class don't remove

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest creating a jsFiddle to illustrate the problem.  I'm pretty sure that if you take the time to build that out, we can offer much better advice.

Comment: I'm so sorry I can't because it's a plugin in Wordpress

Comment: You don't need all those `.ready()` calls. Put all your code in one.

Comment: Can you explain your code for setting the value of "Checkmod1".  It looks like it might be not being assigned properly.  You seem to be setting it to the result of setting a property called "toggled".

Comment: #squint ... still dosen't work

Answer (score 2):

var Checkmod1 = $("#mashmenu-mod-1").data("toggled", "true");

The above line of code will always set toggled to true, it will never enter the else, therefore never removing the class

Comment: I'm sorry my frined ... code (QUISTION POST) has been edit see it  ... var Checkmod1 = $(this).find(".mod-content").data("toggled", "true");

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to set Checkmod1 to be true if #mashmenu-mod-1 is toggled, but data("toggled", "true") does not return the current state of the toggled attribute - it creates and sets an attribute "toggled" to the string "true". See [data() documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Instead, check the state using the following:

```
var Checkmod1 = $("#mashmenu-mod-1").is(":hidden");
```

Comment: My answer still applies.  The answer by Zoheiry is still true too.  data("toggled","true") does not return the state of toggled.

Comment: Okey and think you so much i have fix it by myself